# Creating a function that prevents from selecting a different date before a specific date in the React Date Picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

For example, `this.state.endDate = new Date (" 2019-07-12 15: 00: 00 + 00 ")`. My goal: to block in Date Picker the possibility of choosing a date earlier than or equal to `this.state.endDate` (the date in `this.state.endDate` will change). So far, I managed to block the possibility of choosing a date earlier than the current one. However, I have a problem with setting it to be compared not to the current date but to that of `this.state.endDate`. I use this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker

Code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rt4tzm

```
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import moment from 'moment';


class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      selected: new Date(),
      minTime: this.calculateMinTime("2019-07-12 15:00:00+00"),
      endDate: new Date()
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      endDate: new Date("2019-07-12 15:00:00+00")
    })
  }

  calculateMinTime = date => {
    let isToday = moment(date).isSame(moment(), 'day');
    if (isToday) {
        let nowAddOneHour = moment(new Date()).add({hours: 1}).toDate();
        return nowAddOneHour;
    }
    return moment().startOf('day').toDate(); 
}

  handle = (date) => {
    this.setState({
      selectedDate: date,
      minTime: this.calculateMinTime(date)
    })
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.endDate)
    return (
      <div>
         <DatePicker
            selected={this.state.selected}
            onChange={this.handle}
            excludeOut
            showTimeSelect
            timeFormat="HH:mm"
            timeIntervals={15}
            dateFormat="MMMM d, yyyy h:mm aa"
            timeCaption="time"
            minDate={new Date()}
            minTime={this.state.minTime}
            maxTime={moment().endOf('day').toDate()}
          />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `minDate={this.state.endDate}` . This would prevent the user from picking any dates before the `endDate`.